# Maximum Depth of Binary Tree in scala

Tags: algorithm, scala, binary-tree

I'm doing the exercise on leetcode using Scala. The problem I'm working on is "Maximum Depth of Binary Tree", which means find the maximum depth of a binary tree.

I've passed my code with IntelliJ, but I keep having compile error(type mismatch) when submitting my solution in Leetcode. Here is my code, is there any problem or any other solution please?

```
object Solution {
abstract class BinTree
case object EmptyTree extends BinTree
case class TreeNode(mid: Int, left: BinTree, right: BinTree) extends BinTree

  def maxDepth(root: BinTree): Int = {
    root match {
      case EmptyTree => 0
      case TreeNode(_, l, r) => Math.max(maxDepth(l), maxDepth(r)) + 1
    }
  }
}
```

The error is here : `Line 17: error: type mismatch; Line 24: error: type mismatch;` I know it is quite strange because I just have 13 lines of codes, but I didn't made mistakes, trust me ;)

Comment: Can you post the full error message?

Comment: Line 17: error: type mismatch; Line 24: error: type mismatch;

Comment: Your code has no 17th line. Maybe add some line numbers so we can see what the error message refers to.

Comment: Is your code working locally on your computer?

Comment: `TreeNode` is defined for you. You're stepping on the supplied code by trying to redefine it.

Comment: Thanks guys, just like you mentioned, I didn't use the given code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like an error specific of the leetcode problem.
I assume you're referring to https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-depth-of-binary-tree/description/

Perhaps you're not supposed to re-implement the data structure but just to provide the implementation for `maxDepth`, i.e. `TreeNode` is already given. Try this:

```
object Solution {
    def maxDepth(root: TreeNode): Int = {
        if (root == null) {
            0
        } else {
            Math.max(maxDepth(root.left), maxDepth(root.right)) + 1
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes that the `TreeNode` data structure is the one given in the comment:

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * class TreeNode(var _value: Int) {
 *   var value: Int = _value
 *   var left: TreeNode = null
 *   var right: TreeNode = null
 * }
 */
```